# Why can't I find USB Type-C with flange receptacles?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-c

It seems so strange to me that USB micro B connectors frequently came with a flange, even the cursed micro B + 3.0 typically had flanged connectors, but I have to struggle with my aim to get USB type C ports in on the first try.

The USB-IF's own guide specifies this as a valid option in their "USB Type-C Cable and Connector Specification August 2019"

I seem to recall at some point seeing a publication that specified the mechanical properties of the flange'd version but I can no longer find that publication.

[image: Page 133]

Comment: That is a "funnel", not a "flange". Note the spelling of "receptacle", with an  "a".